# How to increase text height flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I want Text look like this. I tried `height` property of `Text()` but couldn't make like this.  How can I make text like this?

> increasing font is doesnt provide my desire result

```
 Text(
            widget.subscriptionModel.discountPrice!,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 20),
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: use a font from 'tall font' category and set the font size higher. Some examples of such fonts are Alien League, FTY DELIRIUM NCV.

Comment: Can you include sample code that you've tried? Also what about using font size

Comment: Does increasing font size gives you desire result?

Comment: increasing font is not my desire result.

Comment: @OMiShah answer done the trick.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to stretch the text text height without changing its width, you need to use `FittedBox`,you need to tweak the `height` and `width` to get the desired output

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 90,
  width: 80,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    child: Text(
      '149',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Transform.scale`

```dart
Transform.scale(
  scaleY: 2,
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Text(
    "149",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 20,
    ),
  ),
),
```